# Change attribute value of next sibling

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to delete a selected node from a gridview and change the `Id` attribute of every next sibling of that property. It deleted the node but the problem it doesn't change the attribute(decrease the id value by 1). I think the problem is with my for each loops .

```
<Root>
  <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
    <Property Id="1">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="2">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
         <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="3">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="4">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
         <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="5">
    </Property>
  </Class>
</Root>
```

and the code

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("sample.xml");
int value = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
{
    int rowval = row.Index;
    String propertyId = (dgv[0, rowval].Value.ToString());
    String propertyName = (dgv[1, rowval].Value.ToString());
    var nodeTobeRemoved = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']");
    var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete propert set \"" + propertyName + "\" ?", "Confirm Deletion!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        nodeTobeRemoved.RemoveChild(nodeTobeRemoved.SelectSingleNode("Property[@Name='" + propertyName + "']"));
        xDoc.Save("sample.xml");                       
        MessageBox.Show("Property set named \"" + propertyName + "\" from document class \"" + getCurClass() + "\" has been deleted !");
    }
    XmlNodeList ids = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']/Property[@Id='" + propertyId + "']/following-sibling::Property");
    foreach (XmlNode i in ids)
    {
        int.TryParse(i.Attributes["Id"].Value, out value);
        value = value - 1;
        String newValue = value.ToString();
        i.Attributes["Id"].Value = newValue;
        xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
    }
    dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(rowval);
    dgv.ClearSelection();
    getProperties();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I basically changed all the Id variables from the property siblings of the selected property and then I was left with two properties with the same Id's but with different names. Lastly I delete the property with the name that was selected. Voila !

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("sample.xml");
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
        {
            int rowval = row.Index;
            String propertyID = (dgv[0, rowval].Value.ToString());
            String propertyName = (dgv[1, rowval].Value.ToString());
            var propertyNode = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']/Property[@Id='" + propertyID + "']/following-sibling::Property");
            if (propertyNode != null)
            {
                var confirmMessage = "Are you sure to delete propert set \"" + propertyName + "\" ?";
                if (MessageBox.Show(confirmMessage, "Confirm Deletion!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode p in propertyNode)
                    {
                        int value = 0;
                        int.TryParse(p.Attributes["Id"].Value, out value);
                        value = value - 1;
                        String newValue = value.ToString();
                        p.Attributes["Id"].Value = newValue;
                        xDoc.Save("sample.xml");

                    }
                }
            }

            var selectedRow = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']/Property[@Name='" + propertyName + "']");
            selectedRow.ParentNode.RemoveChild(selectedRow);
            xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to select the following siblings of a node you have removed. That's not going to work.

Try like this. (Also, think if you *really* need an ID attribute that does actually nothing at all - you can select the third `<Property>` by stating `Property[3]` in XPath, having an `id="3"` serves no real purpose and causes problems like the one you've just run into.)

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("sample.xml");

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
{
    var propertyId = dgv[0, row.Index].Value.ToString();
    var propertyName = dgv[1, row.Index].Value.ToString();
    var propertyNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']/Property[@Name='" + propertyName + "']");

    if (propertyNode != null) {
        var remainingProperties = propertyNode.SelectNodes("./following-sibling::Property");
        var confirmMessage = "Are you sure to delete property set \"" + propertyName + "\" ?";

        if (MessageBox.Show(confirmMessage, "Confirm Deletion!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode p in remainingProperties)
            {
                var idAttr = p.Attributes["Id"];
                if (idAttr != null) {
                    int value = 0;
                    if (int.TryParse(idAttr.Value, out value)) {;
                        idAttr.Value = (value - 1).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            propertyNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(propertyNode);
        }

        xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
        dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(rowval);
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        getProperties();
    }
}
```

Alternatives

- You could use `propertyNode.SelectNodes("./preceding-sibling::Property").Count + 1` for the value of `@id`, instead of `int.TryParse()` etc.
- drop the `@id` attributes entirely and spare yourself the hassle.

Comment: @OP: Elaborating on Tomalak's first paragraph: `"//Class[@Name='" + getCurClass() + "']/Property[@Id='" + propertyId + "']/following-sibling::Property"` will select nothing because the document now has no Property element with `@Id = propertyId` - it's been deleted. And an empty node-set has no following-siblings. Tomalak solves the problem by grabbing the remaining properties *before* deleting the nodeToBeRemoved.

Comment: Tomalak thanks for your answer but it still cant change the remaining ids ofthe properties :(

Comment: i think is the same as before because there's still no reference of the parentnode inside the remainingproperties variable:(

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code line by line? Things to check: Is `propertyNode` selected correctly? Does `propertyNode.SelectNodes("../Property")` select anything? What about `propertyNode.SelectNodes("./following-sibling::*")`?

Comment: Also, your sample does not contain any Property that would have a `@Name`. Are you sure your sample resembles your *actual* input?

Comment: I cant understand why you cant see that the remaining properties do not exist after deleting the "property node". There has to be a different to do this and am thinking of cloning the nodes .

Comment: I have corrected my code. An `XmlNodeList` dynamically reflects the current state of the document, so you must update your attribute values *before* you remove the other node. Also see the added `null` and conversion success checks.

Comment: Tomalak thanks for your input. I have answered my question below !

Comment: In fact you did the same thing as I did: Removing the property node *after* changing the properties. **Beware of the dangling null pointer exceptions you have in your code.**